# How to update a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using pandas with Python 3.6.
The script reads an Excel file containing two lines of comments, then a line of data with a cell "11:11" which must be splitted in two columns in the result file

Input :

```
ID_TEST         TEST_1
2- Comment_ 1   
3- Comment_2    Naf_TEST_1
Data_1          11:11
```

Output (Wrong):

```
ID_TEST         TEST_1     
2- Comment_ 1               11
3- Comment_2    Naf_TEST_1  11
Data_1          11:11           11
```

Correct Output (Desired):

```
ID_TEST         TEST_1     
2- Comment_ 1       
3- Comment_2    Naf_TEST_1  
Data_1          11         11




    df_dos = pd.read_excel(file_test,sheetname="Dossiers")
    a_dos = str (df_dos.iloc[2][list2_cols[col]])
    b=a_dos.split(sep=":")
    blg = int(len(b)-1)
    i=0

    for i in range (0, blg) :

        for index, row in df_dos.iterrows():

            df_opale_dos.at[index, "   "] = b[i]

            continue
```

I cannot update the dataframe, the split action must be done only on the third line of the target file
I browsed Stack Overflow and the Net about pandas documentation, but I didn't find a solution.
Thank you in advance for your time and your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Splitting string columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` creates new columns which are then remamed as needed:

```
df[['ID_TEST']].join(df.TEST_1.str.split(':',expand=True)).rename(columns={0: 'TEST_1a', 1: 'TEST_1b'})
```

Result:

```
         ID_TEST     TEST_1a TEST_1b
0  2- Comment_ 1        None    None
1   3- Comment_2  Naf_TEST_1    None
2         Data_1          11      11
```

**UPDATE** based on comment below:
If you have a variable `col` containing the name of the column to split (which can change in the loop), then use this variable instead of the column name:

```
df[[col]].join(df[col].str.split(':',expand=True)).rename(columns={0: col+'a', 1: col+'b'})
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Stef, it works perfectly.
In my script, this instruction is in a loop browsing for a number of column names in a list.
In join(df.TEST_1.str.split(':',expand=True)), TEST_1 (column name) is changing for each iteration.
Unfortunately, this case is not described on Stack or anywhere else.
Could you help me to get it solved?
Thank you in advance for your help and time :)

Comment: Merci beaucoup, thank you very much from Paris, France :)

Comment: All is fine for splitting. Thank you again @stef. Loops perform correctly.  I have an additional question. My workbook contains 9 worksheets: in 2 worksheets, I have to split two values separated by " : ", but with no column ; in some other worksheets, column exists, but only one value to replicate on the second column. Can I use the solution you gave me? Thanks for your help :)